# How can I implement a sounds like/soundex search using Google Appengine Full Text Search?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

Is there some way to make a "sounds like" query against an appengine search index?

For example, I have the document:

```
my_document = search.Document(
    doc_id = 'PA6-5000',
    fields=[search.TextField(name='customer', value='John Jackson')])
index = search.Index(name="myIndex")
index.put(my_document)
```

I'd like to be able to do a search like:

```
index.search('Jon Jackson')
```

and see my_document in the search results.

Is there some way to do this with appengine full text search?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Use the tilde (~) operator.  This is fuzzy match, and more powerful than the documentation suggests.